# Font characters not showing in Firefox and IE9

Tags: firefox, fonts, internet-explorer-9, font-face, inkscape

I made a custom font for a set of icons using Inkscape and used the Free Online Font Converter and Font Squirrel to generate the different font types (woff, eot, ttf, svg) and the @font-face code for inclusion.

The font works fine in Google Chrome with the ttf, svg and woff-font and in Internet Explorer 7 and 8, but in FireFox 13 and IE9 certain icons do not get rendered. The other icons of the font do work correctly, so there is no problem with the file getting delivered. Also because the fonts work in Chrome, the conversion seems to have succeeded.

I think the problem has something to do with the type or shape of the icons I'm using, but I can't find anything in particular that differentiates these two icons from the others I have used.

The problem can be reproduced in my ASP.NET project, but also locally using the testfiles which Font Squirrel supplies.

**Update:** Still did not figure out the solution, but I found out that when the same TTF-font is installed in Windows, it does work in Firefox. But when it is referenced through @font-face, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Going to guess it has something to do with the fact that either your fonts or your font's CSS is not being called from the same domain. Both Firefox and IE9 enforce a Same-Domain Origin Restriction. Therefore do not use domains in your link tags or your CSS font-face code.

Comment: My @font-face code is exactly what font squirrel generated and only references the font file, which is in the same directory as the css.

To make it clear: the fonts themselves get loaded, only a couple of charachters are missing. These charachters do not show up in the example file of font squirrel either.

Comment: Ok, I didn't read this carefully enough. Apologies. Sounds strange for sure, but I wonder if the icons are actually present in the web fonts. Be sure to use the 'Expert' mode and turn off 'Subsetting'. Our 'Optimal' setting subsets to MacRoman char set only.

Comment: I fixed the problem, but i'm not entirely sure what did the trick. The first time I turned off subsetting with the original source file it did not work, but when I removed and readded the icon to the source file it did work. Maybe Inkscape saved it differently, or the combination with turning subsetting off solved it. Anyway, thanks for your help :)